# removeEventListener seems to be getting a different version of the handler?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a `Calendar` class, instantiated once, and then an `EventHandler` class instantiated once in the constructor of `Calendar`.  I add event listeners by binding `this` (the `Calendar` object) to them so I can access the `Calendar` object inside of them.  This all works fine.

That is, until I try to add event listeners within an event handler and bind `this` which is still the `Calendar` object to them.  The adding works, but the removing of the event listener doesn't.  It seems like the remove is getting a different copy of the function I passed when I added it.  Here's the adding of the event listener in `Calendar`:

```
this.containerDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", this.eventHandler.calMousedown.bind(this));
```

then in `calMousedown` in `EventHandler`, I do this:

```
this.containerDiv.addEventListener("mousemove", this.eventHandler.calMousemove.bind(this));
```

but then in another handler, I remove that listener like this:

```
this.containerDiv.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.eventHandler.calMousemove.bind(this));
```

but it doesn't remove it.  `this` should be the single `Calendar` object all over the place, but it's as if the remove has a different copy of the function.  I've verified that `this` is the `Calendar` object in all the handlers.  I've also tried to remove the `.bind(this)` on the remove, that didn't work, either.  How is this not removing?

Comment: Ye, because `bind()` will return a new function reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind` creates a new function but you can cache it:

```
var handler = this.eventHandler.calMousedown.bind(this);

this.containerDiv.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
...
this.containerDiv.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
```

Comment: Worked great.  I didn't realize bind creates a new copy.  Many thanks.